# What's a merc-pool in Asimov's The Caves of Steel?

Tags: isaac-asimov

As depicted in the title, page 1 chapter 1, *Conversation with a Commissioner*, what is a merc-pool in the context of this passage:

> A closely coded tape reeled out of the merc-pool's vitals as the small instrument searched and analyzed its memory for the desired information stored in the tiny vibration patterns of the gleaming mercury surface within.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your question answers itself (once the typo is fixed).  The line you quoted makes it pretty clear that a merc-pool is a form of data storage that uses vibration patterns within a pool of mercury to store data.

Answer (score 11):

This is really just a footnote to Ward's answer: early computers used [mercury delay lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_line_memory#Mercury_delay_lines) for storing information and I'm sure Asimov knew of this when writing The Caves of Steel. As it happens, the idea [has surfaced again](http://www.science20.com/news/acoustic_plasmons_could_revolutionize_data_storage) and this is uncannily like Asimov's description of data stored in a mercury surface.